# Задача при вводе данных

Tags: java, scanner

Напишите программу: вводим два целочисленных числа и должны увидеть в консоли сумму этих двух чисел умноженную на три с защитой от пользователя (методы: hasNextInt(), hasNextDouble() и тд).
Вот такую задачу я получил и нужно с помощью класса Scanner сделать эту задачу.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            int a = scan.nextInt();
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                int b = scan.nextInt();
                int result = (a + b) * 3;
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Введите пожалуйста целое число");
        }
    }
}
```

Если вводим первый раз или второй раз не целое число, то должно выводиться в консоль: Введите пожалуйста целое число. Но у меня не получается, подскажите как написать чистый код, а у то у меня какой-то говно код получается

Comment: Что если сделать считываение числа со всеми проверками отдельной функцией?

Comment: @tym32167 а нужно с защитой (методом hasNextInt()) сделать

Comment: Ну так и в чем проблема?

Comment: @tym32167  я вижу что тут говно код и можно сделать лучше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал это так:

```
   public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int a = getIntValueByScan(scan);
            int b = getIntValueByScan(scan);
            System.out.println((a + b) * 3);
        }
    
        private static int getIntValueByScan(Scanner scan) {
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                return scan.nextInt();
            }
            throw new ArithmeticException("Введите пожалуйста целое число");
        }
    }
```

Здесь я вывел наследуемый от `RuntimeException` - `ArithmeticException`, если не требуется выводить ошибку в стектрейс, то верните sout

Answer (score 0):

У меня получился следующий вариант:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showInfo("Введите первое целое число");
        int firstNumber = getNumber();
        showInfo("Введите второе целое число");
        int secondNumber = getNumber();
        showInfo("Результат (firstNumber + secondNumber) * 3 составил: "+calculate(firstNumber,secondNumber));
    }

    private static int getNumber() {
        boolean numberIsCorrect = false;
        int number = 0;
        do{
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                number = sc.nextInt();
                numberIsCorrect = true;
            }catch (Exception e){
                showInfo("Вы ввели не число, повторите попытку, необходимо ввести целое число");
            }
        } while (!numberIsCorrect);
        return number;
    }

    public static void showInfo(String str){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    public static int calculate(int firstNumber, int secondNumber){
        return (firstNumber + secondNumber) * 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте етот код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a, b, result;

    if(scan.hasNextInt()){
        a = scan.nextInt();
        if(scan.hasNextInt()){
            b = scan.nextInt();
            result = (a+b)*3;
            System.out.println(result);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Введите пожалуйста целое число");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Введите пожалуйста целое число");
    }
  }
}
```

Посетите наш сайт, если несложно: [JEasily](https://jeasily.com)